# What is the difference between Models and Repository in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel

I want to know what is the difference between Models and Repository in laravel 5. Both are same or not and what are benefits of repository.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A model and a repository are not the same.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) - `Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as insert new records into the table.` What this is saying, is a Model opens access to a database table. It also allows you to relate to other models to pull out data without having to write individual queries.

A repository allows you to handle a Model without having to write massive queries inside of a controller. In turn, keeping the code tidier, modular and easier to debug should any errors arise.

You could use a repository in the following way:

```
public function makeNotification($class, $title, $message)
{
    $notification = new Notifications;
    ...
    $notification->save();
    return $notification->id;
}

public function notifyAdmin($class, $title, $message)
{
    $notification_id = $this->makeNotification($class, $title, $message);
    $users_roles = RolesToUsers::where('role_id', 1)->orWhere('role_id', 2)->get();
    $ids = $users_roles->pluck('user_id')->all();
    $ids = array_unique($ids);
    foreach($ids as $id) {
        UserNotifications::create([
            'user_id' => $id,
            'notification_id' => $notification_id,
            'read_status' => 0
        ]);
    }
}
```

And inside the controller:

```
protected $notification;

public function __construct(NotificationRepository $notification)
{
    $this->notification = $notification;
}

public function doAction()
{
    ...
    $this->notification->notifyAdmin('success', 'User Added', 'A new user joined the system');
    ...
}
```

Comment: but what if we write all this in Model, the controller will still remain clean. then what's the specific use of repository against model?

Comment: @AmitShah Using a repo allows you to decouple your business logic from your database layer. Silly to mix the 2. Especially if you move away from Eloquent to a different ORM or data storage method. I suggest you have a read of this: http://shawnmc.cool/the-repository-pattern

Comment: Sounds great, but your repository code is coupled to Eloquent and Laravel. I think it's nice to have repositories. But not for portability, there is none.

Comment: Having a repository is not only because of future change in persistence, which happens rarely. A cogent reason to use a repository, is that your data fetch/saving logic might become complex. E.g you want to invalidate a cache (another storage) while you fetch the latest Feeds from FeedRepository. You wouldn't want to move from file to file to implement this.

Answer (score 6):

The repository basically allows you to decouple your business logic from your database layer.

Whilst your eloquent model knows how to find all records for a given entity, your repository could wrap that in business-specific logic:

```
// Eloquent
$users = User::where('active', true)->get();

// Repository
$users = $this->userRepository->getAll(true);

class UserRepository {
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(User $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getAll($active = false)
    {
        if ( $active === true )
        {
            return $this->model->where('active', true)->get();
        }

        return $this->model->all();
    }
}
```

This gives you testability and separation of concerns, your app is no longer tightly coupled to a particular implementation. In doing so, it becomes simpler to switch out the eloquent persistence for talking to a JSON API for example. This becomes easier still when you then you bind an interface to your controllers - something like UserRepositoryInterface - because you can update all uses of that interface just by updating one line in your service provider.

As with anything, though, it's up to you to determine if this is appropriate for your application. Repositories add another layer of complexity to your app that perhaps a small CRUD application won't actually need.